# In Oxygen Bulder, is there any way to set global page width to 100% of the browser window?

Tags: css, design

I prefer to keep my website as dynamic as possible, so I want to set it up to use 100% of the browser width, but I only see an option to use pixels for the width. Is there an easy way to get it to take up 100% instead of a predefined amount of pixels?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work out a solution:

1. Go to Oxygen > Templates.
2. Edit your main template (usually it's called Main or Default).
3. Click on +Add > Fundamentals > Code Block.
4. In the Code Block settings, switch to the CSS tab.
5. Add the following CSS:

```
body .ct-section-inner-wrap {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

6. Click on Apply Code.

This CSS rule overrides the max-width for sections, allowing them to span the full width of the browser window. Remember to save your changes.

Please note that this will affect all sections on your site. If you want to apply this to specific sections only, you would need to add a custom class to those sections and replace `.ct-section-inner-wrap` in the CSS rule with your custom class.

Also, remember to add padding or margins to your inner elements to ensure your content doesn't touch the edges of the browser window.

If you are like me and want this to also work with the Heading Builder element as well, you'd use this code instead:

```
body .ct-section-inner-wrap, body .oxy-header-container {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```